# How to assign class attribute to InputDate in blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to assign a `class` attribute to `<InputDate />` component. I tried using `AdditionalAttributes` but its syntax is not clear to me. What I ended up with is this:

```cs
<InputDate @bind-Value="Model.Task.TaskDate" @attributes="datePickerAttributes" />

@code {
    private Dictionary<string,object> datePickerAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        ["class"] = "form-control"
    };
}
```

It works but looks messy.
Is there a more concise way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overthinking things, you want to assign a class - just do that.

```html
<InputDate @bind-Value="Model.Task.TaskDate" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Hmm, this is what I have tried initially and saw a syntax error. Somehow it works now. I must say I find visual studio somewhat unreliable when it comes to analyzing blazor syntax.

Comment: Yep, there are still issues, but they are working on a  new razor editor that hopefully will work better!

Comment: @jakubiszon look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters - this is a useful feature of Blazor components that allows you to pass arbitrary attributes to a component without having the create dozens of `[Parameter]` properties. VS2019 not showing any issues when I tested it